# Height Field with average normals

Tags: opengl, normals, opengl-compat

I am creating height field and i want to create its normals (face/vertex), I am using Triangles to create a mesh. I already calculated GL quad Normals but confused here for Triangles instead of quads.
I searched the internet and found out that two types of normals exists like per face and per vertex but not found any my code related help.
Here is what i am doing right now to create heightfield.

```
int average_normal()

{ 
glPushMatrix();


GLfloat xdelta=xsize/xsteps;
GLfloat zdelta=zsize/zsteps;
   
glNormal3f(0,1,0);

for (int x=0; x<xsteps-1; x++)
    for (int z=0; z<zsteps-1; z++)
    {
    
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    setMaterialHeight(map[x][z]);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(xdelta*x,map[x][z],zdelta*z);
    setMaterialHeight(map[x+1][z]);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(xdelta*x+xdelta,map[x+1][z],zdelta*z);
    setMaterialHeight(map[x][z+1]);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(xdelta*x,map[x][z+1],zdelta*z+zdelta);   
    glEnd();

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    setMaterialHeight(map[x+1][z+1]);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(xdelta*x+xdelta,map[x+1][z+1],zdelta*z+zdelta);  
    setMaterialHeight(map[x][z+1]);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(xdelta*x,map[x][z+1],zdelta*z+zdelta);       
    setMaterialHeight(map[x+1][z]);
    glNormal3f(0, 0, 1);
    glVertex3f(xdelta*x+xdelta,map[x+1][z],zdelta*z);
    glEnd();
    }
glPopMatrix();
return true;
}
```

How can I calculate its normal?

Answer (score 0):

The normal vector can be computed by the [Cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of 2 vectors. Create a function, which computes the cross product and sets the normal vector attribute:

```cpp
void set_normal_from_cross_product(
    float x1, float y1, float z1, 
    float x2, float y2, float z2)
{
    float nx = y1*z2 - z1*y2;
    float ny = z1*x2 - x1*z2;
    float nz = x1*y2 - y1*x2;
    float len = sqrt(nx*nx + ny*ny + nz*nz);
    if (len != 0.0f)
        glNormal3f(nx/len, ny/len, nz/len);
}
```

In a grid the normal vectors can be computed by the vectors between the adjacent vertices. Write function which computes the vectors between the adjacent vertices and invokes `set_normal_from_cross_product`:

```cpp
void set_grid_normal(int x, int z)
{
    int prev_x = x > 0 ? x - 1 : x;
    int next_x = x < xsteps - 1 ? x + 1 : x;
    int prev_z = z > 0 ? z - 1 : z;
    int next_z = z < zsteps - 1 ? z + 1 : z;

    set_normal_from_cross_product(
        xdelta * 2, map[next_x][z]-map[prev_x][z], 0,
        0, map[x][next_z]-map[x][prev_z], zdelta * 2);
}
```

Use the function to s et the normal vectors:

```cpp
void set_attributes(int x, int z)
{
    setMaterialHeight(map[x][z]);
    set_grid_normal(x, z);
    glVertex3f(xdelta*x,map[x][z],zdelta*z);
}
```

```cpp
for (int x=0; x<xsteps-1; x++)
{
    for (int z=0; z<zsteps-1; z++)
    {
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        set_attributes(x, z);
        set_attributes(x+1, z);
        set_attributes(x, z+1);
        glEnd();

        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        set_attributes(x+1, z+1);
        set_attributes(x, z+1);
        set_attributes(x+1, z);
        glEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is prev_x_z ? not defined?

Comment: Gotcha !!! But nothing is showing when i press keystroke :(

Comment: @Struggler Possibly the normal vector has to be inverted `glNormal3f(-nx/len, -ny/len, -nz/len)`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223464/discussion-between-struggler-and-rabbid76).

Comment: @Struggler Another typo in my code: `sqrt(nx*nx + ny*ny * nz*nz)` -> `sqrt(nx*nx + ny*ny + nz*nz)`

Comment: Ok Thankyou for the effort